# Hashing a string of bounded size

Tags: hash, cryptography, computer-science, sha1

Assuming I have a bounded input string of maximum length 64 characters [0-9,a-z,A-Z]. Given the following code using sha1 hash:

```
var hash = sha1(str).substring(0,n)
```

I want to minimize the integer *n* while still acceptably avoiding collisions.

How to do I calculate the probability of a collision given *n* and an input set size *x*?

Comment: What do YOU think. Share your findings.

Comment: um math? `probability = setlength / 64 ** n`

Comment: Define "avoid collisions"?

Answer (score 1):

There is no length that guarantees that there won't be any collision. Even the full 20-byte SHA-1 does not guarantee that there are no collisions: it is computationally expensive to craft collision, but [it has been done](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-1#SHAttered_%E2%80%93_first_public_collision)). Even a 64-byte SHA-512 value does not give a mathematical guarantee that there are no collisions, but the best known ways to find a collision require more energy than is available in the solar system.

If you want a practical guarantee that there are no collisions (even in the face of hostile input), you can use a cryptographic hash that has not been broken, such as SHA-256.

But if this is for indexing rather than security, hashes are usually not a practical way to ensure the absence of collisions. Use a non-cryptographic hash instead. Non-cryptographic hashes make it easy to craft collisions, but they are faster to compute. If there is a collision, use a secondary hash, a binary search in a sorted data structure or a linear search to resolve the ambiguity. This is how data structures such as hash tables work.

There is one case where you can ensure that there are no collisions: when you're working with a fixed data set. In that case, you can calculate a [perfect hash function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_hash_function) from the data.

Alternatively, hashing may be the wrong tool for the job. Maybe you should keep a central database of indexes instead.